# Identify if the parent of a clicked item has children of a specific type in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('h2').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle(100);
  });
  $('h2').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>
    3. Kathleen
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="text">
      <p>
        Expetenda periculis incorrupte at sed, esse mutat detraxit ius et, oratio dolores patrioque
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>4. Fred</h2>
</div>
```

When I click on a heading I have managed to show or hide the UL below it.  However I only want to change the cursor to a pointer when the div the heading is in contains a UL.   I think I need to use the .has option, but can not work out the correct syntax to select the parent to check for children of type ul and then set the h2.

So in the example Kathleen should have a pointer but Fred should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `div` has `ul` using [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) then target `<h2>`

```
$('div:has(ul) > h2').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('h2').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle(100);
  });
  $('div:has(ul) > h2').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>
    3. Kathleen
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="text">
      <p>
        Expetenda periculis incorrupte at sed, esse mutat detraxit ius et, oratio dolores patrioque
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>4. Fred</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the siblings instead of parent's children.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('h2').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).siblings('ul')) {
          $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle(100);
        }
      });
    
      $('h2').each(function(index, el) {
        if ($(el).siblings('ul')) {
          $(el).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>
    3. Kathleen
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="text">
      <p>
        Expetenda periculis incorrupte at sed, esse mutat detraxit ius et, oratio dolores patrioque
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>4. Fred</h2>
</div>
```